# create a list of files located in multiple directories

Tags: files, ls

I have a set of data files (`*.all`) located in different folders

```
Documents/rawdata/Geob1005/1.all, 2.all, 3.all,...,n.all
Documents/rawdata/Geob1006/A.all, B.all, C.all,...,Z.all          and so on...
```

I have created a file called `datalist.mb-1` in each directory which lists all the `*.all` files located in the same directory using:

```
/bin/ls -1 *.all | awk '{print $1" 58"}' >datalist.mb-1
```

so I get this:

```
Documents/rawdata/Geob1005/datalist.mb-1
Documents/rawdata/Geob1006/datalist.mb-1
and so on...
```

Now I need to create a "master" datalist in `Documents/rawdata/` that points out to all the other datalists inside the directories of `rawdata/`

I need the outcome of the "master" datalist to look like this:

```
Geob1005/datalist.mb-1  -­1 
Geob1006/datalist.mb-1  -1
```

Any idea of how to do this task?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nice skills. Does it have to be in bash, or will python do? Oh, can you put your file paths and code in coding formatting (use these ``)?

Comment: what is the `-1` at the end of `Geob1005/datalist.mb-1  -­1` for, or the 58?

Comment: @Private The 58 is because I need to add a column to the datalist.mb-1 files which describes the format of the data (which in this case is 58)

Comment: @Symin The -1 at the end of 'Geob1005/datalist.mb-1 -1' is to also describe the format of the datalist located in that path.
I am trying to follow a HowTo MB_System tutorial for bathymetry data processing. http://www.ldeo.columbia.edu/res/pi/MB-System/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to do it using Locate, actually I didn't need the full path but using awk was enough to just show just the path from the "geo" subdirectory.

This is how I did it:

`locate ~/Documents/rawdata/*/datalist.mb-1 | awk 'BEGIN {FS="/"} {print $4 "/" $5 " -1"}' > master.txt`

Answer (score 2):

A really simple way to do this would be to use the `locate` command like so:

`locate Documents/rawdata/Geob*/datalist.mb-1 > master.txt`

That is if full paths are okay.

However, if you need the format which you described above with only the "geo" subdirectory and file you could use a simple little python script like this one:

```
#!/bin/python
f = open("/path/to/master.txt","r+")
paths = [x.split("/",3)[-1] + " -1" for x in f.readlines()]
f.seek(0)
f.write("".join(paths))
f.truncate()
f.close()
```

Slightly truncated version of napogeof's answer:

`locate ~/Documents/rawdata/*/datalist.mb-1 | awk -F/ '{print $4 "/" $5 " -1"}' > master.txt`

Comment: I finally managed to do it using **Locate**, actually I didn't need the full path but using **awk** was enough to just show the path from the "geo" subdirectory.
this is how I did it:
Guys I finally managed to do the task using the Locate command

`locate ~/Documents/rawdata/*/datalist.mb-1 | awk 'BEGIN {FS="/"} {print  $4 "/" $5 " -1"}' > master.txt`

Comment: You should post that as an answer. I'm sure plenty of people would find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

*Untested*

You could use bash to make a list of all the files in a single `.txt` file (just use a `find` command to find the 'datalist' files and then pipe that the file).

In python you can use that file list (for example, `datalist_master.txt`) as follows:

```
fi = file.open('datalist_master.txt', 'r')
li = fi.readlines()
new_li = []    

for element in li:
    # get rid of unnecessary path info
    element = element.lstrip('Documents/rawdata/')

    # add last two digits 
    element = element + ' ' + element[-2:]
    new_li.append(element)

fi.close()
print new_li #or save it somewhere
```

This is most certainly also possible in bash (but I do not know how).